# Centering the text in the circle

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem...

HTML:

```
<ul class="circle">
    <li><div class="text">1</div></li>
    <li><div class="text">2</div></li>
    <li><div class="text">3</div></li>
    <li><div class="text">4</div></li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hwpa0uk1/59/)

I want the text in each part to be in the center and straight, not rotated. How should I do it?

Comment: Please always include the relevant code in the question, not only at an external site, as I'm sure that you were pointed out when trying to post the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take an easier approach without all the `transforms`, if not necessary:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.quarter {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.quarter:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  padding: 30px 0 0 30px;
}
.quarter:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
  padding: 30px 30px 0 0;
}
.quarter:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
  padding: 0 0 30px 30px;
}
.quarter:nth-child(4) {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="quarter">1</div>
  <div class="quarter">2</div>
  <div class="quarter">3</div>
  <div class="quarter">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! But the text is not in the middle, maybe you know how to fix it please? :)

Comment: @Roy Just add padding to the relevant corners. I've updated the answer. Also note the change in the `line-height` to keep up with the padding.

Comment: If the size of your circle is fixed you could just try and find the right paddings. But the problem is that the <div>s are actually rectangles which are cut off by the circle border. If you would complete the quarters to rectangles you would see that the text is centered. But css doesn't know that the quarters are cut off. Do you understand that or is it a bit intricate? Sorry, I see that the answer has been improved

Comment: @V.Boersch-Supan Yes I understood, thanks for the explantion too :)

Comment: @Roope Hi, can you please explain me the first css block? `box-sizing: border-box;` I dont understand that so much. Thanks again

Comment: @Roy Basically it defines what will be included in the `width` of an object, making it easier to work with `padding`. But you should really just google that and learn it, there's a ton of articles and guides on the topic. It will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Create a span for each piece of text and rotate it to get the default rotation.

http://jsfiddle.net/www139/psykwc9k/1/

Please tell me if I didn't understand the question.

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(180deg) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(180deg) rotate(45deg);
  transform: skewY(180deg) rotate(45deg);
  padding-top: 40px;
}
li:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-180deg);
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) skewY(-180deg);
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-180deg);
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) skewY(-180deg);
}
li:first-child .text {
  background: green;
}
li:nth-child(2) .text {
  background: tomato;
}
li:nth-child(3) .text {
  background: aqua;
}
li:nth-child(4) .text {
  background: yellow;
}
.circle span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="circle">
  <li>
    <div class="text"><span style="-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg);">1</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="text"><span style="-o-transform:rotate(-135deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-135deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-135deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-135deg);transform:rotate(-135deg);">2</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="text"><span style="-o-transform:rotate(135deg);-moz-transform:rotate(135deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);-ms-transform:rotate(135deg);transform:rotate(135deg);">3</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="text"><span style="-o-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg);">4</span>
    </div>
  </li>

  <ul>
```